# Set SQL field value equal to other field value on insert

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert

I want to insert into a table structure like this:

```
ID | CLIENT_ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | …
```

`ID` is the auto increment primary. `CLIENT_ID` can appear multiple times for multiple versions.

How can i set `CLIENT_ID` on a `INSERT` statement same as the - in this statement - auto generated primary `ID`?

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO clients SET client_id=id, name='test', description='yada'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed that is possible exactly how i wrote it:

```
INSERT INTO clients SET client_id=id, …
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like below (better use a `WHERE` condition)

```
INSERT INTO clients (CLIENT_ID , NAME , DESCRIPTION)
SELECT id, 'test', 'yada'
FROM your_table
WHERE id = 1234;
```